# Castle Windsor Container Validation has problems with open generics

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor

I use Castle Windsor 4.1.1 and for my use case I register open generics.
The container works and can resolve all classes but the container validation can't handle this. The Problem is when the open generic class gets a generic type as an constructor argument, then the validator has potential mismatches for every class where it is used and for any dependency the open generic is used.

I have used the Container Validation described here: [Castle Windsor: is there a way of validating registration without a resolve call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969973/castle-windsor-is-there-a-way-of-validating-registration-without-a-resolve-call)

A workaround is: don't use generic arguments of open generics in the constructor  or to disable the validation completely, which both do not work for me. Can I do something to get the validator functional in this scenario?

Container Setup:

```
var c = new WindsorContainer();
        var collectionResolver = new CollectionResolver(c.Kernel);
        c.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(collectionResolver);
        c.Register(Component
            .For(typeof(IOpenGeneric<>))
            .ImplementedBy(typeof(OpenGenericImpl<>))
            .LifestyleTransient()
        );
        c.Register(Component
            .For<MyProfile>()
            .LifestyleTransient()
        );
        c.Register(Component
            .For<MyClass>()
            .LifestyleTransient()
        );
        c.Register(Component
            .For<MyOtherClass>()
            .LifestyleTransient()
        );
```

Sample Classes:

```
class MyOtherClass
{
    private readonly MyClass _cls;

    public MyOtherClass(MyClass cls)
    {
        _cls = cls;
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    private readonly IOpenGeneric<MyProfile> _s;

    public MyClass(IOpenGeneric<MyProfile> s)
    {
        _s = s;
    }
}

class Profile
{
}

class MyProfile : Profile
{
}

interface IOpenGeneric<out T>
    where T : Profile
{
}

class OpenGenericImpl<T> : IOpenGeneric<T>
    where T : Profile
{
    private readonly T _t;

    public OpenGenericImpl(T t)
    {
        _t = t;
    }
}
```